# R is gone after publishing

Tags: android, eclipse

For some unknown reason, after I published my app at google play, my R file is gone and my app doesn't compile!

I tried:

Removing all R.android from the app.

Doing project -> clean (in my eclipse). I cleaned it before removing the R.andorid and after.

Changed my build target from 2.2 to 2.1, and back (with clean in between).

Nothing helped me.

What can I do?

Comment: Where is the correlation between publishing and R file?

Comment: I have no idea. My app got published, and when I returned to it at eclipde, the R file is gone.

Comment: My suggestion is to learn how to use IDEA. Eclipse is a nightmare when it comes to doing android projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created my project again and copied the R file. So easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in an xml (in the res folder) somewhere probably which is preventing your R class to be generated. Look at those files or the error log in eclipse usually has some information.

EDIT:
Also, restart eclipse.

Comment: Thats weired. I don't remember touching my xml's. They look fine. On my error-log is "Marker <num> not found".

Comment: I'm not sure what that means in context to your application, but you may want to check that out. Also, if you want a fresh series of error logs, clear the error log console, and do a clean.

Comment: Sometimes error messages for xml files don't show up by the file names in the project explorer. I only find them by opening up each one. (I typically find the files that have errors from the error log console however)